# Реализация Promise.race

Tags: javascript, promise

Наткнулся в интернете на реализацию Promise.race:

```
const promiseRace = promises => new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
  promises.forEach(promise => {
    promise.then(res => {
      resolve(res);
    });

    promise.catch(rej => {
      reject(rej);
    });
  });
}));
```

Но после его выполнения появляются ошибки: unhandled rejection, в отличии от оригинального Promise.race. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Прежде чем вызывать resolve/reject надо проверять, промиз ещё в состоянии pending. Например завести флаг, что resolve/reject ещё ни разу не вызывались

Comment: @AlexeyTen попробовал завести bool переменную и обернуть вызов resolve/reject: if (flag) { reject(rej); flag = false; }. Не помогает :(